# API - 000Webhost

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm encountering an issue when calling the API using the POST method with `axios` but when I call the API using GET method, it works successfully.

On the backend side, I have deployed Laravel on **000Webhost**.

Please help me resolve this error. Thank you very much.

I want to successfully call the API using the POST method.

Comment: this is error: (failed)net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: Is the POST route defined in the API?